# MATLAB figure convert into PDF without cutting out parts

Tags: matlab, figure

I didn't use to have problems with this figure, but after enlarging the font size with 'export setup' parts on the left and right side are cut out (if I convert the MATLAB figure into PDF). If I convert the MATLAB figure into JPEG format, the whole figure is displayed.

I made a new MATLAB figure with the old font size, but the parts are still cut out.

Comment: How do I use export_fig?

Comment: You Google it, download it and read the documentation ;). Matlab sucks exporting plots, that is an alternative used by everyone that needs good quality figures.

Answer (score 0):

did you try print?

```
F = getframe(gcf);
orient portrait
print ('-dpdf', 'myimage.pdf')
```

alternatively to portrait you can also use `orient landscape` or `orient fill`. Especially fill should resize it so that it fits.